# Refering to <ol> within <dd> jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm really struggling with the following function and can't seem to figure it out. I have a product filter list which is made up of `<li>` items in an `<ol>` which is located in `<dd>` and then a `<dl>`

So the locations is:

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list"><dd class="even"><ol><ul>
```

I'm trying to apply a scroller i found specifically to the `<ol>` (which is unnamed)

I'm using the following code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('ol').slimScroll({
        height: '250px'
    });

});
```

Which works, but applies the scroller to every `<ol>` on my site. How can I target the exact `<ol>` in the above path?

I've tried this but still have no luck:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#narrow-by-list.dd.ol').slimScroll({
        height: '250px'
    });

});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers
Chris

Comment: `jQuery('#narrow-by-list ol')`

Comment: Perfect! I've been searching all afternoon for that! Thanks

Comment: Just read a little about CSS selectors. This is, what jQuery uses there (with some extensions ...)